# Shift to the right or left bend arrow in xymatrix package

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, cite-package, xymatrix

We suppose that we have a code build with `xy` package. For example this or another MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\Omega \ar@{->}[r] \ar@/{}^{2pc}/[r] & \Upsilon \ar@{->}[r]  & \Psi
}
\end{document}
```

What are the command to shift a curved arrow to left or to right without altering the positions of symbols or adding `&`'s appropriately?

Thank you very much in advance everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the “in” and “out” directions (section 1.6 of the guide):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
\Omega \ar[r] \ar@/{}^{2pc}/[r] & \Upsilon \ar[r]  & \Psi
}
\]

\[
\xymatrix{
\Omega \ar[r] \ar@(u,u)[r] & \Upsilon \ar[r]  & \Psi
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have more control with `tikz-cd`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Omega \arrow[r] \arrow[r,bend left=90] & \Upsilon \ar[r]  & \Psi
\end{tikzcd}
\]


\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Omega \arrow[r] \arrow[r,bend left=90,looseness=1.7] & \Upsilon \ar[r]  & \Psi
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]